# How to call a Powershell script using batch script and pass an object array

Tags: arrays, batch-file, powershell

I'm a newbie in Powershell scripting. I'm trying to write a script that reboots a list of servers,pings, checks if application services are all up and then RDP's onto the servers.

My issue is with passing the list of servers from an array variable to another script I call reboot. See below;

Batch script to call and bypass ps1 executionPolicy (ParamBypass.bat):

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '"%PowerShellScriptPath%"' -ServerList '%2' -SCreD '%3' -SEnv '%4'"

--actual Batch call code : ParamBypass.bat PingRBAuthPass.ps1
```

Powershell Script (PingRBAuthPass.ps1):get a list of servers and stores the into array

```
$NSRVList = Import-Csv .\SMachines\Servers.csv | Where-Object {$_.ENVName -eq "RND"} | Select-Object -Property ENVName,FND,DB,APPS
ParamBypass.bat /reboot.ps1 $NSRVList
```

Powershell reboot Script:

```
param(             
[string[]]$ServerList,
[string]$SCreD,
[string]$SEnv
)
Function Database
{
[Object[]]$RBSrv
$RBSrv = $ServerList
Foreach ($srv in $RBSrv) {
if($srv.DB) {
--do something
   $NSRVList = $RBSrv | Select-Object -Property ENVName,FND,APPS
   } else { & "FND" }
}
}    
& "Database"
```

If I run this the contents of the array which look like this:
variable $NSRVList output whiles in PingRBAuthPass.ps1

```
ENVName FND       DB        APPS
------- ---       --        ----
RND     srv003529 srv002983 srv003528
RND                         srv003527
RND                         srv003526
RND                         srv003530
```

variable $NSRVList output whiles in reboot.ps1

```
@{ENVName=RND; FND=srv003529; DB=srv002983; APPS=srv003528}
```

I want the structure of the array to stay intact.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot combine the everything into a single script?

Comment: Well for one: It is easier for maintenance. I'm also not familiar with the robustness of powershell and how much line of code it can handle in one script. So opted for this type of coding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your confusion stems from the fact that you believe that $NSRVList is an array of strings. But, if you see below example; you will see that it is actually a custom object

contents of so_question.csv

```
ENVName,FND,DB,APPS
RND,srv003529,srv002983,srv003528
RND,,,srv003527
RND,,,srv003526
RND,,,srv003530
```

call import-csv

```
PS C:\Users\sqlchow\Desktop> $a = Import-Csv .\so_question.csv

PS C:\Users\sqlchow\Desktop> $a  #uses the default display format for objects

ENVName                       FND                           DB                            APPS                         
-------                       ---                           --                            ----                         
RND                           srv003529                     srv002983                     srv003528                    
RND                                                                                       srv003527                    
RND                                                                                       srv003526                    
RND                                                                                       srv003530
```

but, actually $a is actually a customobject

```
PS C:\Users\sqlchow\Desktop> write-host $a
@{ENVName=RND; FND=srv003529; DB=srv002983; APPS=srv003528} @{ENVName=RND; FND=; DB=; APPS=srv003527} @{ENVName=RND; FND
=; DB=; APPS=srv003526} @{ENVName=RND; FND=; DB=; APPS=srv003530}

PS C:\Users\sqlchow\Desktop> $a | gm


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
...
...
APPS        NoteProperty System.String APPS=srv003528  
DB          NoteProperty System.String DB=srv002983    
ENVName     NoteProperty System.String ENVName=RND     
FND         NoteProperty System.String FND=srv003529
```

Comment: I'm think on using files to write new array lists on them and continuously update them until I complete the process. Is there a way to convert the PSCustomObject to any array or better yet load a .csv file into an array.